# How to model ZeroMQ async multithreading server

Tags: scala, zeromq

I want to implement a high-throughput server that accepts multiple clients. Every request should query a database, so I need some kind of async behavior.

I followed the `ROUTER`-to-`REQ` pattern from documentation + `Futures`, so I ended with this "architecture":

```
trait ZmqProtocol extends Protocol {

  private val pool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool()
  private implicit val ec: ExecutionContextExecutor = ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(pool)

  val context: ZMQ.Context = ZMQ.context(1)
  val socket: ZMQ.Socket = context.socket(ZMQ.ROUTER)
  socket.bind("tcp://*:5555")

  override def receiveMessages(): String = {

    while (true) {

      val address = socket.recv(0)
      val empty = socket.recv(0)
      val request = socket.recv(0)

      Future {

        val message = new String(request)
        getResponseFromDb(message)

      } onComplete {

        case Success(response) =>
          //  Send reply back to client
          socket.send(address, ZMQ.SNDMORE)
          socket.send("".getBytes, ZMQ.SNDMORE)
          socket.send(response.getBytes(), 0)

        case Failure(ex) => println(ex)
      }
    }

    "DONE"
  }
}
```

I understand this won't work because I'm sharing socket in `Future` so I need a better model. I know the ZeroMQ sockets are fast and creating several worker threads would be enough on input side, but if the bottleneck is on the database side and if I need to do some other work while waiting for DB, I presume all my threads would soon be exhausted.

Would it be too much of an overhead if I create new socket and bind on `ROUTER` in every `Future` or is there some better solution?

Also, for Scala developers: is there a way to force **`onComplete`** being executed on main thread (I suppose it would solve the issue)? Thanks!